# Vuelidate "OR" validator example

Tags: vuelidate

OK - searched for quite a while all over and cannot find an example or using the OR validator from Vuelidate. The one mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate/issues/212) is not valid and the issue resolves without providing a valid OR example. The [docs mention it exists](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-builtin-validators) but do not have any example that we could find. Anyone have or know of an valid example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a field that take multiple validation types, like signing in with a username or email address, you can do something like this

```js
data () {
  return {    {
   multiusername: '',
  }
},
validations: {
  multiusername: {
    required,
    mycustomval: or(email, alphaNum)
  }
}
```